# RESTful API conventions: how to represent a regular expression search?

Tags: regex, rest, api-design

I have a RESTful API endpoint with a Mongo backend. I allow users to filter their queries using GET parameters, e.g. to get analytics for the `/about` page on the site:

```
/page-analytics?filter_by=pagePath:/about
```

I would like to extend this to support regular expression filters, e.g. to get analytics for all pages below `/about` on the site:

```
/page-analytics?filter_by=pagePath:/about/.*
```

My question is really about the most conventional way to represent this in my API.

Ideally I'd like only to use regular expression search when the user actually intends to use a regular expression (as it's more expensive than a simple find). So it would be good to indicate that the user intends to use a regular expression.

I was wondering if the best way would be to have a whole new parameter:

```
 /page-analytics?filter_by_regex=pagePath:/about/.*
```

Or perhaps to use a different operator for regexes, e.g. the tilde below:

```
/page-analytics?filter_by=pagePath:/about
/page-analytics?filter_by~=pagePath:/about/.*
```

Are there conventions about this?

Comment: There are no standards about this. There are ad-hoc query languages like rql: https://github.com/persvr/rql. Or you can send an expression in your favorite query language, e.g. sparql if you use rdf to describe metadata.